# re-generate DataGrid columns at run time in UWP

Tags: c#, uwp-xaml

I use MVVM pattern in UWP app. 
VM defines a list of DataGrid columns. The following code-behind I use for generating columns during UserControl load:

```cs
private void DataGrid_AutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
            {
                if (ViewModel.PresentColumns.Contains(e.PropertyName.ToLower()))
                {
                    var templateName = e.PropertyName + "DataTemplate";
                    var templateColumn = new DataGridTemplateColumn();
                    templateColumn.CellTemplate = Application.Current.Resources[templateName] as DataTemplate;
                    templateColumn.Header = e.PropertyName;
                    e.Column = templateColumn;
                }
                else
                {
                    e.Cancel = true;
                }
            }
```

XAML:

```
<msgrid:DataGrid  Name="GridTargets" Grid.Row="1"
                 Grid.Column="0"
                 ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.TargetSteps}"
                 SelectedItem="{x:Bind ViewModel.SelectedTargetStep, Mode=TwoWay}"
                 AutoGenerateColumns="True"
                 GridLinesVisibility="All"
                 CanUserResizeColumns="False"
                 AutoGeneratingColumn="DataGrid_AutoGeneratingColumn"/>
```

VM:

```
  public IEnumerable<string> PresentColumns { get; private set; }
```

I need 'replace' the grid during run time. All "available grids" (lets say 10 grids overall) are predefined; the ViewModel.PresentColumns is generated at run time for every "available grid". I think to re-generate columns during run. DataTemplates for all available columns are predefined in global resources. 
Is it doable or there is another architectural solution?
It is not desirable keeping few grids in the UserControl.

That is DataGrid form Windows Community Toolkit - ns Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls. 
The initial task is: dynamicaly generate DataGrid columns from VM; constrain of the MS DataGrid - property name, which define a grid column has to be defined in compile time.
I have Class Foo with 100 properties. The collection of the Foo is a ItemsSource of DataGrid. Each property is a custom object and define columns in the grid. There is DataTemplate for every property in global resources for presentation data in the grid. I need show different groups of properties in one view, groups toggle instantly from VM.
I see the following workarrounds:
1. Instantly 're-generate' just grid (questionable)
2. Wrapp grid in UserControl, load-unload UserControl, that will force generate new grid every time (doable).
3.Generate grid with all 100 columns and hide/show columns on demend from VM(doable, not desirable).

Actually I realise that I am looking for the way to trigger the AutoGeneratingColumn event; changing the ItemsSource property works for this task. Thus, I am going 'artificially' change the source in VM. I consider your comment as answer on my question. Thank you  Barry.

Comment: It's not clear about what you are trying to do. Does this datagrid means community toolkit datagrid? Why do you need to re-generate columns at runtime? Do you have you own data for the datagrid?Any MCVE[https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve] to help us understand your request?

Comment: I seems understand what you mean by saying generate at runtime. But your question "re-generate grid" still makes me confusing. Do you mean re-template the datagrid's appearance. Or you mean a group to group your columns? The event will trigger when ItemsSource property is changed. But it seems you will not change the source?

Comment: Thanks for your confirm. I will post an answer about the event. By the way, I see the notification that you are a new user. So next time if you have an edit you can add something like: Edit to notify others that you are editing your original post. That would make your post more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the confirm from the original poster. The OP want to look for the way to trigger the AutogeneratingColumn event. This has been wrote in [the official doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/controls/datagrid_guidance/customize_autogenerated_columns). Where you can see the following:

"The AutoGeneratingColumn event occurs one time for each public, non-static property in the bound data type when the ItemsSource property is changed and the AutoGenerateColumns property is true."